# Android Facebook SDK, owner some 3rdparty

Tags: java, android, facebook, sdk

Android -  Facebook SDK [Advertising]

1. The third party is the owner of the Android application.
2. Install Facebook SDK
3. We create a facebook accout and give it an Application id.
4. We have been doing advertising for 6 months.
5. He then replaces the application id with own id.

Is this forbidden ?, I really didn't find the answer on google.

Personally I see no reason to be banned, the client has accepted this option.

Thanks for every answer.

Answer (score 0):

Application id is a unique id provided by facebook specifically for your application. With this id only facebook identifies your application. If it is changed then your application could not be identified.